# Using a dictionary (or other structure) key in a variable name

Tags: python, django

This is a dictionnary used to pass it's keys to the loop below.

```
SIZES = OrderedDict((
    ('image_main', (800, 800)),
    ('thumbsize_big', (200, 200)),
    ('thumbsize_small', (100, 100))))
```

The instance in this code is a model instance. The key passed to the dictionary is equivalent to the field name i'm trying to get the value into. For example in this case the field path would read 'self.instance.image_main'.
Problem is that 'self.instance.key' with key being the key from the dictionary doesn't seem to work. I tried many things, such as concatenating 'self.instance. + key' or even 'self.instance[key]' but it didn't work.

```
def execute(self):
    for key, value in self.SIZES.items():
        save_dir = self.base_dir + self.slug + '_' + key
        # Save images in fields. 
        if self.has_iterated == 0:
            # I need self.instance.main_image with main_image dynamically generated form the key
            self.instance.key = self.saving_path + self.slug + '_' + key + '.' + self.image_format
```

Do you see another way to get this working ? The goal is not to hardcode the field name in the loop, but have it passed from above the code where I set the variables. Code is simplified of course, but in the real context this is to avoid DRY.

Update: revised code with Lambo implementation.
Second iteration of loop seems to cause problem.

```
 def execute(self):
    for key, value in self.SIZES.items():
        save_dir = self.base_dir + self.slug + '_' + key
        # Save images on disk. No iteration required: at each iteration, a new file is created and stored.
        self.save_image(self.resize_image(self.image, value),save_dir, self.PNG_COMPRESS, self.JPG_COMPRESS)
        # Save images in fields. Iteration numbered: otherwise field is overwritten at each iteration
        if self.has_iterated == 0:
            setattr(self.instance, key, self.saving_path + self.slug + '_' + key + '.' + self.image_format)
        elif self.has_iterated == 1:
            setattr(self.instance, key, self.saving_path + self.slug + '_' + key + '.' + self.image_format)
        else:
            setattr(self.instance, key, self.saving_path + self.slug + '_' + key + '.' + self.image_format)
        self.has_iterated += 1

    return self.instance
```

Comment: what exactly does not work? self.instance[key] is what u need here.

Comment: This is what I expected but it produces: 'Document' object does not support item assignment. Document being my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `setattr()`. `setattr(x, 'y', z)` is equivalent to `x.y = z` (note that the second argument is a string - in your case, it will be the `key` string). So in your case, you could do:

```
setattr(self.instance, key, self.saving_path + self.slug + '_' + key + '.' + self.image_format)
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. I run several of these in the loop, it seems the first one runs fine, but not the subsequent ones. Do I need to 'purge' something at each iteration using that ?

Comment: Quite tricky to know without seeing more of your code. The above solution should always work providing you are passing a valid object, string and value to the `setattr` function.....

Comment: Very strange that I don't get this error message when I put only the first iteration: SuspiciousFileOperation at /list/
The joined path (/media/dir/test_image_main.png) is located outside of the base path component (/Users/COMPANY/Documents/Apps_And_Sites/Python_Apps/Django-Apps/dirworld/src/media). As if the iteration change something.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the value you are passing in `self.saving_path + self.slug + '_' + key + '.' + self.image_format`, not with the `setattr()` methodology. Try running with `setattr(self.instance, key, 1)` to help debug the problem....

Comment: But it works fine when I hardcode the names of the fields: all iterations are fine with the path. When I put 1 with setattr I get "'int' object has no attribute 'image'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101293/discussion-between-lambo477-and-robert-brax).

Comment: That is the way to do it thanks. Problem with  second iteration was issue with dictionnary value. once corrected it worked.